# Verifying two references point to the same object in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

If I'm running the debugger in Eclipse, how do I check to make sure a field in one class is pointing to the same object as the field in another class? I set up breakpoints in both classes, and I'm pretty sure both fields point to the same object, but how would I verify this? (The codebase is much too big to trace the references around.)

I believe Eclipse takes care of this, if I hover over the field in question. (It says, MyClass@79d99e6b. The address refers to the object in RAM, right?)

Comment: Actually, IIRC, the Eclipse debugger frequently mentions an "id" for each object it can see, and I believe values marked with the same id are actually reference-equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address should point to the RAM address yes.
I'm not familiar with eclipse's debugger but if it is giving you an address, and they are the same for both, then yes it should be the same reference.

Also, depending on what language you are using, you could throw in a little variable that is a pointer to the address of the object.  (ex, in c++ it's the "&x" syntax if x is the variable.  assuming I am remembering that correctly)  Then you can check the value of your reference variables.

Answer (score 2):

They are same if they have the same [`identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: That's not quite true, generally speaking.  On e.g. 64-bit JVMs, memory addresses are too big to fit into an `int`, so you can actually get `identityHashCode` collisions.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Hmm. Yes, I guess if the addresses are too big to fit in an int then there can be collisions. And if one wants to programmatically determine they are same then `==` should be used. I feel like downvoting my own answer :)

Comment: To be fair, just for debugging purposes this is probably sufficient, as collisions are still quite rare.

Comment: Yes but for debugging, instead of evaluating `System.identityHashCode(o1) == System.identityHashCode(o2)` one might just as well evaluate `o1 == o2`, no?

Comment: As I understand it, the Eclipse debugger provides the `toString`s of the objects in question, and the objects in question had the basic "MyClass@79d99e6b" `toString` implementation that uses the `identityHashCode`.  So looking at the `toString`s would tell you if the `identityHashCode`s matched.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way in eclipse is by looking at the variables tab in debug mode.  If the variable has the same id, you can be sure they are the same reference.  The id=? is located under the value header on the Variables tab.